# Is it overkill to shutdown a VM before taking an LVM snapshot for backup purposes?

Tags: files, lvm, virtual-machine, backup, data

As part of a backup strategy for hundreds of VMs built on LVM volumes, I am considering:

1. Shutdown the VM.
2. Take a snapshot of the LVM volume containing user and application data, including MySQL and LDAP databases.
3. Start the VM.
4. Backup the LVM volume.
5. Delete the snapshot.

My intention is to ensure data consistency, especially for the databases.  Assuming that I do this during a time of low usage, is this reasonable or overkill?  I have to take into account that a user might visit the server at the exact moment it is down but for the benefit of perfect data consistency it is a cost I might be willing to take.

An LVM snapshot does not guarantee data consistency in general, right?  Even though an LVM snapshot freezes a filesystem at a particular point time, there is no way of knowing if the MySQL database is in the middle of a transaction at that moment, for example.  Some databases but not all offer backup tools to ensure data consistency but that would mean I need a backup strategy at the application level, which sounds like a lot of work.

In the above use case of a VM containing web apps that are not being used at night, we can afford a few milliseconds of downtime but ideally I would like to avoid it.

Comment: ah that actually is a feature of the database: Typically, database backends are supposed to be random crash-safe, so that at **every** point in time, the data on disk is certain to be consistent (e.g. no half-updated columns). But: not all database backends actually do guarantee that, nor are all databases configured to do that! But, yes, if you ask me (someone "db conservative" who thinks you cannot compare mongoDB+redis to a proper database, because they don't allow that certainty, and hence all performance gains are results of unfair comparisons), you should be able to snapshot *anytime*!

Comment: See (don't have the MySQL docs at hand) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-file.html , mid paragraph for how a "during runtime" snapshot looks to the database: just as if something suddenly crashed, the database will have to restore a consistent state from the write-ahead log, but *it's not a problem, that's just what it means to use a proper database*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This means a proper database should maintain data consistency on the file system at a transactional level.  But what if an application or series of services is in the middle of an operation that consists of multiple independent transactions?  For example, a user is registering.  The database is updated but the registration e-mail has not been sent out yet or something like that.  Taking a snapshot at this point would not reflect a correct/complete system state.

Comment: Then you go and have a friendly talk with your application designer :) modern Databases allow you to define a kind of consistency mode for a whole transaction. So, for anything that should be atomic from the view of the database, there's a database solution. Nothing in this world can solve the email verification issue you describe; if the verification happens after you take your backup but before the next backup, that's simply lost state in case you need the backup... Your backuping process can hold your own world, but not the world of your users.

Comment: So your position is that shutting down the VM before a backup is overkill?

Comment: well, yes. Your database itself guarantees consistency, and also, by the way, it has consistency-guaranteeing backup functions, almost certainly :) conditions are of course that for "consistency" all data is part of what you actually backup!